# Can we use lldb in shell script(Bash)?

Tags: bash, shell, lldb

I need to execute few lldb commands in sequence using bash script. In my script, it opens lldb in terminal but do not execute rest commands.

Comment: `In my script, it opens lldb` Show your script.

Comment: `lldb <<EOF` then put the commands on the following lines, followed by `EOF` line.

Comment: The same way you feed multiple lines of input to any other command.

Comment: Note you can also use lldb's `-o` options to issue your commands on the lldb run line.  You can repeat the -o as many times as you want, lldb will execute all the commands in order.  Just make `-o quit` the last command.  That's sometimes easier than having to deal with HERE directives, and it's nice for development because you can just copy the command from your script and run it directly on the command line.